# LINQ lambda nullable sum in where condition

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have the following LINQ query which would work as needed except that not all of the records are returned where there are no records in the linked tables.

```
Dim query as List(Of Project) = context.Projects.Where(Function(a) a.Invoices.Sum(Function(b) b.InvoiceAmount) - a.Payments.Sum(Function(c) c.PaymentAmount) <> 0)
```

If a Project has an entry in the invoices table but no entry in the payments table then the record wont be returned.

I have reviewed a similar question [Linq to Sql with lambda sum as a where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000482/linq-to-sql-with-lambda-sum-as-a-where-condition) but could not work out how to correct the above query.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add a condition to return all projects with no payments?

(I'll do this in C#, but I'm sure you can quickly translate it to VB.NET)

```
var query = context.Projects.Where(p => p.Payments.Count() == 0 || p.Invoices.Sum(i => i.InvouceAmount) - p.Payments.Sum(pm => pm.PaymentAmount) != 0)
```